# How to separate word by comma, space, period(.), tab(\t), parentheses(), brackets[], and curly braces({}) characters in wordcount hadoop?

Tags: java, regex, string, hadoop2, word-count

I am practicing MapReduce with Cloudera turotial [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/tutorial/CDH5/topics/ht_wordcount1_source.html). However, currently the tutorial only split words by space with this regex in Java:

`private static final Pattern WORD_BOUNDARY = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\b\\s*");`

However, in addition to space `"\\s*"`, I also want to define separate words by comma, period(.) and tab(\t), parentheses(), brackets[], and curly braces({}) characters. In other words, I define a word as a string that has one or more alphanumeric characters bounded by two non alphanumeric characters. For example:

- (cece54) has one word "cece54" bounded by `()`
- {dwd] has one word "dwd" bounded by `{]`
- xxx) has one word "xxx" bound by `<space>` and `)`
- so on and so forth.

So how should my regex be written in order to obtain this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a word as one or more consecutive alphanumeric characters, then split on one or more consecutive non-alphanumeric characters, i.e. `"\\P{Alnum}+"` or `"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"`.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gAOXv6/1) for example.

You can prefix the first one with [`(?U)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS), i.e. `"(?U)\\P{Alnum}+"`, for full international unicode support.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm! You save my thanks giving! God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Not super familiar with regular expressions, but I believe the code is

`"\\s*\\b(\\s*|\t*|\{*|\}*)"` et cetera

The java docs for pattern are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Thank you for your fastest help, but java returned error with your code.

MyWordCount.java:83: error: illegal escape character
 static String regex = "\\s*\\b(\\s*|\t*|\{*|\}*)";
                                          ^
MyWordCount.java:83: error: illegal escape character
 static String regex = "\\s*\\b(\\s*|\t*|\{*|\}*)";

Answer (score 0):

All delimiters can be separated by | pipe symbol and it can be directly splitted use split method of Java String class. That would be simple instead of defining the template.

I have added few remaining can be added as required.

```
 String str = "Hello World{!]as";
 String splits[] = str.split(" |\\[|\\]|\\{");
 for (String split: splits) {
     System.out.println(split);
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and better) to use a character class, e.g. `[ \\[\\]{]`?

Comment: whether you are referring to create character array class for all delimiters?

Comment: I was referring to you creating a 4-way [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`|`) expression of 4 single-character expressions, instead of a single [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[]`) with the 4 characters. I didn't say anything about arrays or any other Java construct, it was all about regex constructs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the alternation and character class. I confused it with java character class.